# How to display list of lists in different divs in django

Tags: django, templates

I have list of lists, which I'm sending to html:
views.py:

```
data =  (('13:20','Dave','Stivenson'),('14:15','John','Scaletta'),('11:00','Dave','Johnston'))
return render(request, 'test.html', {'rows': data})
```

test.html:

```
{% for r in rows %}

     <div class="col-md-3">
                <span style="color:white;font-size:14px">{{ r }}</span>
            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It displays list in div, but how can I display not list, but list strings in div? Like:

```
13:20                   Dave               Stivenson
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case all you would need to do is

```
{% for r in rows %}
    <div>
        {{ r.0 }} {{ r.1 }} {{ r.2 }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However you will have to add your styling into this answer.

Comment: tried and got:  Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'r[0]. Just setting {{ r[0] }}

Comment: done, r.0, r.1, r.2 worked, but if f.e. r.2 is empty, it just replaces it with next row r.0

Answer (score 0):

If number of values are known as in your case, there are 3 values then you can do

```
{% for x, y, z in rows %}
    <div>
        {{ x }} {{ y }} {{ z }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```